# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1), basemap plots

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib-basemap

I try to plot three different variables lat,lon,dectime with dimensions (3245,450),(3245,450) and (3245,).
The error type i get is obviously asscociated with the dimension of the variable dectime. Here is the part of the code which actually produces the plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
m = Basemap(projection='cass',llcrnrlat=39,urcrnrlat=54,\
    llcrnrlon=2,urcrnrlon=20,resolution='i',lon_0=10,lat_0=40)
xi, yi = m(lon1, lat1)
print(xi.shape,yi.shape)
cs=m.pcolor(xi,yi,dectime1,cmap='jet')
m.drawparallels(np.arange(39., 54., 3.), labels=[1,0,0,0], fontsize=10)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(2., 20., 3.), labels=[0,0,0,1], fontsize=10)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawstates()
m.drawcountries()
cbar = m.colorbar(cs, location='bottom', pad="10%")
plt.title('NO2 tropospheric column')
plt.show()
```

Is there a way i can make this plot work?

Comment: File "<ipython-input-46-4953a9f2a49a>", line 8, in <module>
    cs=m.pcolor(xi,yi,dectime1,cmap='jet')

Comment: the whole error:

Comment: File "C:\Users\Andrew\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5903, in pcolor
    X, Y, C = self._pcolorargs('pcolor', *args, allmatch=False)

  File "C:\Users\Andrew\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5734, in _pcolorargs
    numRows, numCols = C.shape

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: What are the shape of `xi`, `yi`, and `dectime1`?

Comment: xi (3245,450)  yi(3240,450) and dectime(3450)...this is where the fault lies...at the dimensions of dectime, but i wonder if there is a way to complete the plot

Comment: All of them must have the same shape.